# Is it faster to combine all documents in one collection or to separate them?

Tags: mongodb

*Sorry, this has to be a duplicate of another question, but i can't seem to find it...*

I'm trying to design a geospatial dataset in MongoDb and have certain documents(features) show up in certain layers. My question is now:

When i want to show a specific layer (so a specific set of features), is it faster to go trough a combined list of all documents and only return the ones that have a "layer7" value on their **indexed** field of "layer_number"?

Or is it faster to separate the different features in a separate "layer7_collection" and return just the full set of all features in the collection?

this document is mainly about joins and embedding of data or not, and so is of little help: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would go with keeping an attribute of `layer_number` like you described and add an index on it if that is what you are querying mostly by that attribute or maybe some compound indexes. I don't think there is a wrong answer though. I have seen implementations look up collections dynamically and even databases however I personally find them messy but I have seen a few home brewed examples done very well. Similar to Django Tenant https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas